# No quiero declarar la misma variable en diferentes archivos Arduino

Tags: arduino

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo un programa en Arduino y no me funciona el código en archivos a parte. Este código de abajo que está bien es el archivo .ino principal.

Voy haciendo el código por partes, que las partes se llama archivo.h menos el principal que se llama archivo.ino.

```html
// Include el código de la librería.
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// Inicializa la librería con sus pines indicados.
// RS, RW, Enable, D4, D5, D6, D7.
//LiquidCrystal lcd(8, NULL, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

// Declarar a partir de aquí el lcd.
#include "MenuPrincipal.h"

// Pin 10 para saber que es luz de fondo.
// const PROGMEM byte LuzFondo = 10;

// Variables.
enum BOTONES : const byte
{
  ARRIBA = A1,
  ABAJO = A2,
  IZQUIERDA = A3,
  DERECHA = A4,
  ENTER = A5
};

byte GetPressedKey()
{
  while (true)
  {
    if (digitalRead(ENTER))
      return ENTER;
    else if (digitalRead(DERECHA))
      return DERECHA;
    else if (digitalRead(IZQUIERDA))
      return IZQUIERDA;
    else if (digitalRead(ARRIBA))
      return ARRIBA;
    else if (digitalRead(ABAJO))
      return ABAJO;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200); // 115200

  // La pantalla es de 20 caracteres y 4 filas.
  lcd.begin(20, 4);

  // Indicar luz de fondo como salida.
  // pinMode(LuzFondo, OUTPUT);

  // Configuración de pines como salidas digitales.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  // Configuración de pines como entradas digitales.
  pinMode(ARRIBA, INPUT);     // Arriba. A1.
  pinMode(ABAJO, INPUT);      // Abajo. A2.
  pinMode(IZQUIERDA, INPUT);  // Izquierda. A3.
  pinMode(DERECHA, INPUT);    // Derecha. A4.
  pinMode(ENTER, INPUT);      // Ok / Enter. A5.

  lcd.clear();                          // Borra la pantalla y su posición superior izquierda.
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);                  // Línea 2 del LCD.
  lcd.print(F(" Pantalla principal ")); // Muestra título en la LCD.

  // Almacena la tecla pulsada en la variable.
  BOTONES botonInicial;

  while(true)
  {

    // #####################################################

    // Almacena en la variable una tecla pulsada.
    botonInicial = GetPressedKey();

    // #####################################################
    
    Serial.println(botonInicial);
    Serial.println(ENTER);
    
    // ¿Haz pulsado la tecla Enter?
    if (botonInicial == ENTER)
    {
      // Sí. Se ejecuta esta función.
      lcd.noCursor(); // Oculat cursor.
      lcd.noBlink();  // Cursor no parpadeando.
      Serial.println(F("Boton ENTER pulsado."));
      Menu_Principal();
    } 
    delay(50); // Para mayor estabilidad entre lecturas.
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

Este otro es el segundo archivo llamado MenuPrincipal.h.

```html
#include "NombreReles.h"

  static void  FueraRango()
  {
    // Limpiar pantalla.
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    Serial.print(F("Fuera de rango      "));
  }

static void Menu_Principal()
{
  // Contador de teclas y navegador.
  byte opcion = 0;
  bool salir = false;
  const PROGMEM byte SELECCION_MENU = 8;

  // Oculat cursor.
  lcd.noCursor();

  // Cursor no parpadeando.
  lcd.noBlink();

  // Limpiar pantalla.
  lcd.clear();

  do
  {
    //******************************************************************
    // Dibujo el menú principal.
    const PROGMEM String MENSAJES[] =
    {
      "** MENU PRINCIPAL **", // Posición 0.
      "  ESTADO PRINCIPAL  ", // 1
      "  NOMBRE RELES      ", // 2
      "  NOMBRE SENSORES   ", // 3
      "  ENTRADA ANALOGICA ", // 4
      "  CONFIGURACION     ", // 5
      "  ACERCA DE...      ", // 6
      "  AYUDA             ", // 7
      "  EXTRA             ", // 8
      "  INICIO            ", // 9
      "                    ", // 10
      ">"                     // 11
    };

    switch (opcion)
    {
      case 0:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);     // Línea 1 del LCD.
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[0]);  // ** MENÚ PRINCIPAL **
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[1]);  // > ESTADO PRINCIPAL
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[11]); // >
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[2]);  //   NOMBRE RELÉS
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[3]);  //   NOMBRE SENSORES
        break;

      case 1:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[0]);         // ** MENÚ PRINCIPAL **
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[1]);         //   ESTADO PRINCIPAL
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[2]);         // > NOMBRE RELÉS
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[11]);        // >
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[3]);         //   NOMBRE SENSORES
        break;

      case 2:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[0]);         // ** MENÚ PRINCIPAL **
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[1]);         //   ESTADO PRINCIPAL
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[2]);         //   NOMBRE RELÉS
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[3]);         // > NOMBRE SENSORES
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[11]);        // >
        break;

      case 3:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[0]);         // ** MENÚ PRINCIPAL **
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[4]);         // > ENTRADA ANALÓGICA
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[11]);        // >
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[5]);         //   CONFIGURACIÓN
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[6]);         //   ACERCA DE...
        break;

      case 4:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[0]);         // ** MENÚ PRINCIPAL **
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[4]);         //   ENTRADA ANALÓGICA
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[5]);         // > CONFIGURACIÓN
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[11]);        // >
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[6]);         //   ACERCA DE...
        break;

      case 5:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[0]);         // ** MENÚ PRINCIPAL **
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[4]);         //   ENTRADA ANALÓGICA
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[5]);         //   CONFIGURACIÓN
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[6]);         // > ACERCA DE...
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[11]);        // >
        break;

      case 6:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[0]);         // ** MENÚ PRINCIPAL **
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[7]);         // > AYUDA
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[11]);        // >
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[8]);         //   EXTRA
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[9]);         //   INICIO
        break;

      case 7:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[0]);         // ** MENÚ PRINCIPAL **
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[7]);         //   AYUDA
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[8]);         // > EXTRA
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[11]);        // >
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[9]);         //   INICIO
        break;

      case 8:
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[0]);         // ** MENÚ PRINCIPAL **
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[7]);         //   AYUDA
        lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[8]);         //   EXTRA
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[9]);         // > INICIO
        lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
        lcd.print(MENSAJES[11]);        // >
        break;

      default:
        FueraRango();
        break;
    }
    // Fin de pintar el menú principal.
    //******************************************************************

    // Leer pulsador ingresada por el usuario.
    botonInicial = GetPressedKey();

    // Validar el tipo de pulsador.
    if (botonInicial == ENTER)
      //if (digitalRead(A5) == HIGH)
    {
      switch (opcion)
      {
        case 0:
          //
          break;
        case 1:
          NombreReles_Principal();
          break;
        case 2:
          //OpcionC();
          break;
        case 3:
          //
          break;
        case 4:
          //
          break;
        case 5:
          //
          break;
        case 6:
          //
          break;
        case 7:
          //
          break;
        case 8:
          return;
          salir = true;
          break;
        default:
          FueraRango();
          break;
      }
    }
    delay(50);

    // ¿Has pulsado Abajo?
    if (botonInicial == ABAJO)
    {
      opcion++;
    }
    delay(50);

    // Entonces si pulsas pulsador Arriba.
    if (botonInicial == ARRIBA)
    {
      opcion--;
    }
    delay(50);

    // Si está en la última opción, salta a la primera.
    if (opcion > SELECCION_MENU)
    {
      opcion = 0;
    }

    // Si está en la primera posición, salta a la última.
    if (opcion < 0)
    {
      opcion = SELECCION_MENU;
    }

    // Uso la tecla escape como salida.
  } while (salir == false);
}
```

**El compilador Arduino IDE 1.8.19 me dice esto:
'botonInicial' was not declared in this scope**

Concretamente en este código.

```html
    // Leer pulsador ingresada por el usuario.
    botonInicial = GetPressedKey();
```

Si ya lo declaré en el archivo principal. ¿Por qué me dice declararlo otra vez?

¿Hay alguna solución?

La que conozco es hacer el código en el mismo archivo.

Saludos.

Comment: Cada librería usa sus propias variables, no te queda otra.

Comment: No es una librería, es el mismo código pero dividido en otras partes, como si fuera uno. Tal vez porque lo he llamado archivo .h. ¿O debo crearla de otra manera?

Comment: En el momento en que separas el código en otro archivo, no tiene acceso a las variables de los demás. Da igual que lo compiles a .dll o que sea .h, no puede acceder a variables que no tiene declaradas. Lo que te recomiendo es que aprendas a pasar variables como parámetro y devolverlas. De esa manera tus funciones pueden ser independientes, estar en cualquier archivo. Le pasas los parámetros de entrada que necesites y te devuelven un valor, no hace falta tener variables compartidas entre diferentes archivos, porque solo tu archivo principal necesita mantener el estado.

Comment: ¿Si pongo los archivos a parte en vez de llamarse .h que se llame .cpp o no tiene nada que ver? Es decir, ¿me pasa lo mismo?

A pesar de esto. Tendría que declarar las mismas variables de cada archivo. Entros lenguajes como C# modo consola no me pasa.
Al final miraré lo de las funciones si no me queda otra o pongo todo el código en el mismo archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En C/C++ las variables son conocidas sólo dentro del archivo fuente donde fueron declaradas.

Si quieres acceder a esa variable desde otro archivo fuente, debes usar la declaración `extern`.

En este ejemplo, el sketch declara una variable `volumen`, que puede ser usada directamente:

```
#include "menu.h"

int volumen = 10;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.print("Antes ");
   Serial.println(volumen); 
   ...
```

Por otra parte, también tenemos un `#include` del archivo `menu.h`, donde tenemos una función que sube el volumen en una cierta cantidad. Para esto tenemos que decir que `volumen` es una variable declarada en otra parte (el linkage-editor se encarga de ubicarla):

*menu.h*

```
extern int volumen;

void subir_volumen(const int valor) {
  volumen += valor;
}
```

La declaración es igual que la declaración original, anteponiendo `extern`.

#### Demo

*sketch.ino*

```
#include "menu.h"

int volumen = 10;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Antes ");
  Serial.println(volumen); 
  subir_volumen(11);
  Serial.print("Después ");
  Serial.println(volumen);   
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

*menu.h*

```
extern int volumen;

void subir_volumen(const int valor) {
  volumen += valor;
}
```

produce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]